# Angular Material md-content compresses simbling element

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have an **md-content** element that compress a simbling element when it is over flow. Here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/kevinbarrientos/pen/ZWXmVG) where you can delete the content inside `<md-content></md-content>` and you'll see how its simbling (i.e. `<div layout="row"..></div>`) gets its original size.

Is that the expected behavior, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress this behavior, one way to do this is setting your `<div>` to `flex-shrink: 0`.

Using `layout="row"` on the sibling `<div>` is setting it to `display: flex`, allowing it to compress its content to accommodate its growing sibling `<md-content>`.

Comment: Thanks for enlighten me. While you're solution solves the problem, I think it would be better to use angular-material directives. In this case I acomplish the same result by using flex="none" in my div. I would like upvote your answere but I can't.

Comment: No problem. You may still be able to mark an answer correct, with the check box, which will get you a little close to voting privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alex's explanation I solved my problem by adding `flex="none"` to the **md-content** simbling **div**. However, Alex's solution would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

use **display:block** & **float** like :

```
<div layout="row" style="display:block">
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Previous section" ng-click="seccionesCtrl.anterior()" style="float:left">
                A
            </md-button>

            <md-button class="md-icon-button next" aria-label="Next section" ng-click="seccionesCtrl.siguiente()"style="float:right">
                b
            </md-button>
</div>
```